# How to redirect service email notifications sent to root

Tags: email, monitoring, postfix

How can a linux box be set up to send service emails from ' "service name" @ "machine id" ' to a non-root email account?

Example1:

```
to: manager@mail.com  
from: cron@machine**1**.com
```

Example2:

```
to: manager@mail.com  
from: mdadm@machine**2**.com
```

Services set up email notices with idiomatic syntax. Checking just

```
grep -Eir "(MAILADDR|MAILTO|-m)(\ )*(=)?(\ )*root" /etc/*
```

turns up Recipients:

```
/etc/anacrontab:MAILTO=root  
/etc/cron.d/0hourly:MAILTO=root  
/etc/crontab:MAILTO=root  
/etc/mdadm.conf:MAILADDR root  
/etc/smartmontools/smartd.conf:DEFAULT -a -n standby,7,q -S on -m root -M exec   /usr/libexec/smartmontools/smartdnotify -n standby,10,q  
/etc/sysconfig/smartmontools:# smartd_conf_opts="-H -m root"
```

(There probably are other ways - in addition to MAILADDR, MAILTO & -m - that packages name the notification recipient.)

Sender
root?

Is finding/changing those files the way to get them to mail to manager@mail.com? An account alias maybe?
Is it possible to set the sender to service@machineId?
Is creating a user and/or local mailbox required for "send only"s?

Related:
[how to redirect all email to a single external address?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195029/how-to-redirect-all-email-to-a-single-external-address)
[Redirect specific e-mail address sent to a user, to other email-recipients](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163148/redirect-specific-e-mail-address-sent-to-a-user-to-other-email-recipients) (procmail)

Platform:
Centos 7
postfix

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file
`/etc/aliases`

Under `# Person who should get root's mail` set the recipient with an entry similar to:
  `root: email@il0veb00b5.xxx`

Then run:
  `newaliases`

I think no need to restart postfix...

Comment: If I understood correctly the question...

Comment: The 
# Person who should get root's mail
#root:          marc
in /etc/aliases
followed by newaliases looks like the answer to me @BiG_NoBoDy

When I try it out, & it works, I'll credit you and close the q.

Comment: Cool, happy if it helps